# jq compare a list of elements and find odd one out

Tags: javascript, jquery, compare, element

hi is there a way to compare a few elements

lets say

```
<ul>
   <li>Cat</li>
   <li>Dog</li>
</ul>
```

if i use ajax it returns

```
<ul>
   <li>Ant</li>
   <li>Cat</li>
   <li>Dog</li>
   <li>Fish</li>
</ul>
```

i need to blink `ant` and `fish` to indicate they are new there.

any ideas ?

Comment: why not fix your ajax call so that it only returns the new items instead of the whole list all over again?

Comment: Thought about that but i dont have a solution in my head how to show the new ones all the ajax does it returns the updated list and i cnt think of a way to just bring up the list of `ant` and `fish` coz i cant differ them from the others if that makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not quite obvious what you want, but maybe something like this (looks for matching text of li in existing ul ands add a class 'new' for new li's found and append them to the existing ul?)  :

```
$currentUl = $('ul'); // this is the 'ul' with its li children u have on the page
//responseUl is the 'ul' string ur getting from the ajax call
$(responseUl).children('li').each( function (index, elem){
    if ( $currentUl.find(':[innerHTML=' + $(elem).text() + ']').length < 1 ){
        $currentUl.append( $(elem).addClass('new' ));
    }
});
```